# .txt reader and printer

Tags: java, bufferedreader, filereader

I am working with the java IDE ready to program. I am trying to make my program ask for a 4 digit pin number. I can store the number in a .txt file but I want to be able to print it out in the console. so say you have the pin number 1234 it would be stored in a file named Bank_Pin.txt you could write some code that allows you to have it printed out. here is what I am using to store the number:

```
                    int pinnum = c.readInt();
                    System.out.println ("Now creating the text fle Bank_Pin.txt.");
                    TextOutputFile a;
                    a = new TextOutputFile ("Bank_Pin.txt");
                    System.out.println ("Writing text file!");
                    a.println (pinnum);
                    a.close ();
                    System.out.println ("Done!");
```

This is placed inside of a while loop and an if else if statement that asks if you already have a code. If not, you will be prompted to make on. but if you do, I am trying to make it so you can print the code out and compare it to the code that will be input.

Answer (score 0):

I never worked on IDE ready. But I found the below code in internet. can you try this

```
Console c = new Console (); 
c.print("Your PIN Data");
```

Answer (score 0):

I have never worked with "Ready to Program" but I assume that it will respond to code like any other IDE I have used will (e.g. Eclipse and NetBeans). It seems like you'd need the `Scanner` and `PrintWriter` classes to make your life easier. The `Scanner` class would be great for checking if a file exists and the `PrintWriter` class for writing out your files. That being said, I would try something like this:

```
while(true){
    Scanner fromFile, fromUser = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean exists = false;
    int pin;

    try{//Attempts to open the file "Bank_Pin.txt" and read in a saved pin
        fromFile = new Scanner(new File("Bank_Pin.txt"));
        pin = fromFile.nextInt();
        exists = true;
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("No saved pin exists");
    } finally {//Closes open resources
        if(fromFile != null)
            fromFile.close();
    }

    if(!exists) {//If there isn't a saved pin
        System.out.print("Please input a pin: ");
        while(true) {//Ask for a pin until a valid one is given
            try{
                pin = sc.nextInt();
                if(String.valueOf(pin).length() != 4)//pin given isn't 4 digits
                    throw new InputMismatchException();
                break;
            } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
                System.out.print("\nPin input was not valid. Please reinput: ");
            }
        }
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new File("Bank_Pin.txt));
        out.println(pin);
        out.close();
        System.out.println("\nPin has been saved: " + pin);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Saved pin: " + pin);
    }

    fromUser.close();//Close input from keyboard
}
```

Hopefully this is what you're looking for. All of the try-catch-finally statements are for safety purposes but you can remove them if you want.